# Implement reverse in Haskell that runs in linear time

Tags: haskell, performance, complexity-theory

I'm just learning Haskell, so sorry if my question is stupid. I'm reading learnyouahaskell.com and now I'm at chapter 5 "Recursion". There's an example of implementation of standard 'reverse' function:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' [] = []  
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

But it seems that it runs in O(N^2) time, while the standard reverse runs in O(N) (I hope so). The following code illustrates this:

```
sum (reverse [1,2..1000000]) -- runs pretty fast
sum (reverse' [1,2..1000000]) -- never finishes
```

So, I started thinking how to implement my own reverse faster. It's pretty easy to do in imperative languages. Maybe I need some more advanced material from subsequent chapters to do this? Any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It can be implemented efficiently using an extra accumulator parameter, like the second parameter of `fac` in this example:

```
factorial n = fac n 1
  where
    fac 0 r = r
    fac n r = fac (n-1) (r*n)
```

If you just want to know how it's done in the standard library, you can also [look at the source code](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#reverse).

Answer (score 15):

`reverse` is defined in the [Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/GHC-List.html#reverse).

You can implement it as:

```
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: Doesn't this suffer from the classic stack issues of `foldl`?

Comment: The version Kru supplied is straight from the source. Note the contents of the list are not evaluated only their position is. Also if you do not use the entire reversed list the list is never created.

Comment: @3noch i think that's the case with `foldr` but not with `foldl`

Comment: I would comment that this is actually the case of "more advanced material from subsequent capters", conjectured by OP. In particular this implementation is discussed in the chapter "Higher order functions", http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions, subsection "Only folds and horses"

Answer (score 10):

```
reverse l =  rev l []
  where
    rev []     a = a
    rev (x:xs) a = rev xs (x:a)
```

Comment: Which is the one coming from GHC source https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#reverse.

Answer (score 1):

```
foldl (\acc x -> x:acc) [] xs
```

This runs in O(n). The idea is pretty simple - you take an empty list(accumulator) and transfer elements to it from top to bottom.